# How to Format the nested string json property serialized json in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, json.net

I am facing problem to serialized or format nested string JSON.
Here is the input: Data can have dynamic values

```
{
  "Id": 33,
  "Data": "{\n    \"$Datatype\": \"Val1, Val2\"\n }",
  "Name": "Test"
}
```

I want the output without any special characters like \n, , \ etc like:

```
{
    "Id": 33,
    "Data": {
        "$Datatype": "Val1, Val2"
    },
    "Name": "Test"
}
```

Comment: Deserialize the JSON, then deserialize the contents of the Data member of the result again.

Answer (score 1):

Data property was serialized twice. To fix it try this code

```
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

jsonParsed["Data"] = JObject.Parse((string) jsonParsed["Data"]);

json = jsonParsed.ToString();
```

Comment: {
  "Id": 33,
  "Data": "{\n    \"$Datatype\": \"Val1, Val2\"\n }",
  "Name": "Test"
}this is dynamic I can't hardcode jsonParsed["Data"] like that and JSON string can have [\n, \t,\\] etc. Please let me know I can get rid of that senerio.

Comment: @mohdafzal What is the problem? Show me another json that doesn' t work properly with this code.

Comment: JSON values are dynamic it can be any JSON values like.
 
{
  "Id": 33,
  "Data": "{\n    \"$Datatype\": \"Val1, Val2\"\n }",
  "Name": "Test"
}

Or

{"id": 1520, "enabled": true, "valid": null, "Default": null}